# Changing row (location) of Button in GridLayout Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How do I swap the position of btn3 and btn in the GridLayout?

```
    final Button btn = new Button(this);
    final Button btn2 = new Button(this);
    final Button btn3 = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("2");
    btn2.setText("4");
    btn3.setText("2");
    final GridLayout gl = (GridLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    gl.addView(btn);
    gl.addView(btn2);
    gl.addView(btn3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the order in which you add the buttons.

```
gl.addView(btn3);
gl.addView(btn2);
gl.addView(btn);
```